# Improving HVAC post Remodel

Tags: hvac, ducts, central-heating, noise-reduction

We are living in a house that was originally built in the 80s with a gas furnace and forced air.  Prior to our purchase, the house underwent a significant remodel including the addition of two rooms and vaulting of the living room ceiling.  With the remodel the duct work that originally traversed the house to two bedrooms was truncated.  To provide heating to the two additional rooms at the addition flex duct work was installed.  The layout is attached.

The main issue that we are having is that as a result of this configuration there is a very disproportionate amount of air being dumped into our master bedroom and bath.  When the furnace fan kicks on it is extremely loud, and will often wake me up (measured at 55-60dB from my bed).  As we now have a child on the way providing adequate heat to our soon to be nursery is more important.  I have trialed partially closing the vents to preferentially divert air to the flex, although this results in worsening turbulence and noise to our bedroom.  Attached is a general layout of the configuration.

I am looking for any recommendations that could improve our situation in regards to better heat distribution and decreased noise.

[image]

Comment: Was the same air handler used? In my experience these type of remodels they try to use the original equipment. When line sizes are not built properly and trunk lines used there is little to be done about noise close to the air handler and because the unit is now undersized heating is sub optimal. When going through major revisions like this (where the ducts were not usable) I usually suggest converting to mini splits at least in part. Gas is normally less expensive to run but if the home is not comfortable is it worth it? . Chech out mini splits for both quiet and adding heat/ac to zones.

Comment: Do you have access to change any of the ductwork (such as it's in an exposed basement) ir is it hopelessly sealed up in walls where you'll need another remodel to fix this cluster<bleep>? Obvious thing that springs to mind is two flex ducts to "low output" not one with a T, or else a much bigger one with a T. And perhaps a longer section taking a detour on the way to the master bedroom/bath, rather than "short, sweet, and noisy"

Comment: The other thing that would be helpful is where the intake(s) or return ducts are. I do agree that it is a cluster<beep> and probably done by a general contractor not hvac trained people. We normally do not put registers on the end of trunk ducts. Additionally with the long flex to the 2 new bedrooms with no return they probably won’t have good flow unless a booster fan is installed but that is a possibility that will pull some of the forceful air from the high flow locations.